# Recursive function failing while inorder traverse in tree ds

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

I am trying to implement tree data structure but I am stuck and having trouble understanding how to create a recursive function for inorder traversal for my binary tree.

This is what i have done so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node
        self.left = None
        self.right= None



    def inorder_traversal(self):
        if self.node != None:
            return inorder_traversal(self.node.left)
            return self.node
            return inorder_traversal(self.node.right)
```

**I don't seem to understand what's wrong.**

*Test inputs:*

```
root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(3)
root.right = Node(4)
```

Error:

```
File "trees-implementation.py", line 23, in inorder_traversal
    return inorder_traversal(self.node.left)
NameError: name 'inorder_traversal' is not defined
```

Comment: use `self.inorder_traversal` as the function does not exist on its own.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've defined your traversal functions with respect to the Node. Does this make sense to you?

You should define a traversal with respect to the Tree, not the Node. The Node does not know it belongs to the tree, it's a dumb object.

Define the node.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right= None
```

Define the tree. Also define your traversal methods here.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def inorder_traversal(self):
        def _inorder(root):
            if root != None:
                yield from _inorder(root.left)
                yield root.value
                yield from _inorder(root.right)

        return list(_inorder(self.root))
```

Initialise the tree with a root, and then traverse it.

```
tree = Tree(root)
tree.inorder_traversal()
[3, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Hi, so besides being a little complicated, I wanted to figure out why did you chose to use a list to return the values the other things is, that the traverse still continues when root is None.

Comment: Here's a sample output: (preorder, inorder, postorder): ['child1', None, 'child2']
[None, 'child1', 'child2']
['child1', 'child2', None]

Answer (score 0):

First, could you check if when you have your object, you don't put a parameter in

> root = Node()

Then are you sure you can have several returns in your inorder_traversal() function ?
Finally, the function is in the class Node() so if you call it try to add self.yourfunction

Comment: hi i am not sure how that's going to helpful (i may be wrong). My Node() returns an error when passed without a parameter..cuz.. that's how's defined. Error i get is exactly that: missing parameter

Comment: @geekidharsh Did you bother to look at the other answer?

Comment: hi @CallCentreExecutive i am actually writing down my response for you. I like your answer but I have a few questions. :)

Comment: i will be sending it your way shortly @CallCentreExecutive